# floating grid with 1px border - in IE9 at certain browser widths the horizontal border disappears

Tags: css, grid

I've created a grid of floating image where the image is set to 100% and there is a 1px border between them. This problem only seems to only happen in IE9... If you resize the browser slowly you will get to a point where the horizontal border disappears. Here's the test: http://zerostatic.com/float_grid/

CSS:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
ul{
    width:100%;
}
li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    width:33.333333333%;
}
.li-inner{
    border:1px solid red;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
img{
    width:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <ul>
         <li>
            <div class="li-inner">
              <a href="#" class="full-image"><img src="http://www.zerostatic.com/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </li>
            <li>
            <div class="li-inner">
              <a href="#" class="full-image"><img src="http://www.zerostatic.com/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </li>
         <li>
            <div class="li-inner">
              <a href="#" class="full-image"><img src="http://www.zerostatic.com/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </li>
         <li>
            <div class="li-inner">
              <a href="#" class="full-image"><img src="http://www.zerostatic.com/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </li>
         <li>
            <div class="li-inner">
              <a href="#" class="full-image"><img src="http://www.zerostatic.com/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </li>
         <li>
            <div class="li-inner">
              <a href="#" class="full-image"><img src="http://www.zerostatic.com/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </li>
         <li>
            <div class="li-inner">
              <a href="#" class="full-image"><img src="http://www.zerostatic.com/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </li>
         <li>
            <div class="li-inner">
              <a href="#" class="full-image"><img src="http://www.zerostatic.com/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="li-inner">
              <a href="#" class="full-image"><img src="http://www.zerostatic.com/01.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is two-fold:

1. Firstly, you're not using any kind of CSS reset for that page. That means you're letting a whole lot of guess-work to each individual browser. There are a myriad of CSS resets out there and they all work fine. I suggest you have your pick from these three: [Iain MacDonand's Strppd](http://iainspad.com/strppd-css/) , [Eric Meyer's Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or the reset within the [HTML5 Starter Pack](http://sickdesigner.com/resources/HTML5-starter-pack/index.html) which is, basically, an extensive, HTML5 version, of Strppd
2. And secondly, yes, IE is a bit thick when it comes to calculating non-integer values, which is why I recommend strapping in the very useful box-sizing technique as detailed in this short [Paul Irish post](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Comment: Thanks, I've added strppd and the css: * { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; } But still no luck in IE9. Also tried normalize.css. I've updated the link here: http://zerostatic.com/float_grid/